# Create a python function that accepts two integer parameters, finds all prime numbers between them and return these primes in a list

Tags: python, function, primes

**I want to create a python function that accepts two integer parameters finds all prime numbers between them and returns these primes in a list.**

*I did a part of the code but I'm stuck in printing prime numbers and turning them into a list.*

```
a,n = map(int,input("Enter a and n: ").split())
def isPrime(a,n):
   if n <= 1:
       return False
   for i in range(a, n+1):
       if n % i == 0:
           return False;

   return True
```

Comment: Create an empty list, run a for-loop over all numbers in range and append to empty list each number tested positive for prime.

Comment: Your function `isPrime()` returns `True` or `False`. To use it to solve your problem, in a loop outside the function, call `isPrime()` repeatedly on *one* candidate prime and use the value returned to include it in or exclude it from your list.

Comment: You need a loop in the function but it must begin with 2. "a" shouldn't be a parameter because for testing "n" for prime it doesn't matter where you start or end the range of values to test.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your `is_prime` function shorter like that:

```
a,n = map(int,input("Enter a and n: ").split(" "))
def is_prime(a):
    return all(a % i for i in range(2, a))

out = []
for i in range(a, n):
  if is_prime(i):
    out.append(i)
print(out)
```

The output for **a = 0** and **n = 90** would be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89]
```

Comment: My own personal style preference is to fully specify the condition `a % i != 0` for clarity. This is especially the case for beginners who likely won't be experts in python truthiness. Also, it's worth noting that by convention 0 and 1 are not prime.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your solution so that you only check for numbers with a value of 2 or higher. Your solution allows negatives, which is not correct.

Also, your clause for checking for the primes is wrong, as you check if `n` has divisors. Instead, you want to check if every number in **[a, n)** interval has a divisor. The interval is **[a, n)** because a prime number has only 1 and itself as divisors.

My code does just that, so if the algorithm finds that a number in the **[a, n)** interval has no divisors, then it will append it in an empty list that I created before going through the loop, and return the list, then print it.

```
a, n = map(int, input("Enter a and n: ").split())

def isPrime(a, n):
    lst = []

    for i in range(a, n + 1):
        if (i > 1):
            for j in range(2, i):
                if (i % j == 0):
                    break
            else:
                lst.append(i)

    return lst

print(isPrime(a, n))
```

My output for **a = 0** and **n = 100** is:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

My code is a modified version of [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/prime-number-intervals).